# What is an operator in mathematics?

Tags: functions, terminology, operator-theory

Could someone please explain the mathematical difference between an operator (not in the programming sense) and a function? Is an operator a function?

Comment: Every operator is a function, but not all functions are operators. Precisely what qualifies a function to be an operator varies with the context -- it might be best to think of "operator" as a context-dependent shorthand for "function of the (particularly nice?) kind we're considering in this subdiscipline".

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm. Could you please give an example? Is operator a function so frequently used that it is elevated to the status of an _operator_? Also, there are some properties of operators like _associativity_ for which I am not aware of a counterpart in _functions_ or _relations_. That makes me believe that oeprators might be fundamentally different from functions. Is that true?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Is not every function an unary operator? At least I see nothing prohibiting us from calling it such.

Comment: @Leonid: You can certainly choose to make the extra conditions on an operator void when you flesh out the concept for your field of choice. However, there are large areas of mathematics where an "operator" is usually understood to mean "linear transformation" (also known as "linear operator"), and under that convention not all functions are operators.

Comment: According to Wikipedia an operator is a function whos domain and co-domain are *vector spaces* (or more generally *modules*).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on your comment it sounds like you're actually asking about **operations**, not operators. A **binary operation** on a set $S$ is a special kind of function; namely, it is a function $S \times S \to S$. That is, it takes as input two elements of $S$ and returns another element of $S$. We can denote such an operation by a symbol such as $a \star b$ and then demand various additional properties of this operation, such as

- **associativity**: $(a \star b) \star c = a \star (b \star c)$,
- **commutativity**: $a \star b = b \star a$

and so forth. On the other hand, an arbitrary function $f : A \to B$ between two sets only takes a single input and returns an output which is not necessarily of the same type, so one can't speak of associativity or commutativity for such a thing. One might call a function $f : A \to A$ a **unary operation** but one still can't speak of associativity or commutativity for such a thing.

Comment: On the other hand (noted because this seems to confuse the OP), we can also speak of associativity and commutativity in functional notation $f(f(a,b),c)=f(a,f(b,c))$ and $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$. It is conventional to use the _word_ "operation" about $f$ whenever we're particularly interested in properties of this kind, but that linguistic convention does not express any fundamental difference in what the thing _is_.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I now have a better understanding. So operations are also functions.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, would you mind shortly explaining the difference between an operator and operation?

Comment: @bellpeace: this should be asked as a separate question, except that I think it has already been asked (use Google, not the built-in search).

Comment: Not only are operations functions, but from what I gather, the converse is also true: all functions are operations. Every function is either a unary operation $f:S \to T$ or a $k$-ary operation $f:S_1 \times \cdots \times S_k \to T$. Would anyone disagree with this?

Comment: I'm wondering, should the "operator-theory" tag be removed from this question? I think that substituting it for the tag "binary-operation" might be a good idea for the following reasons:
$\tag*{}$
1. An operator's domain and codomain are vector spaces (or modules); an operation's domain and codomain need only be sets, hence a difference in contexts.
$\tag*{}$
2. When talking about an operator, you are thinking of the process; when talking about an operation, you are thinking of the operands and the result.
$\tag*{}$
3. Most people with this question will have a binary operation in mind.

Answer (score 11):

It is a pity that mathematics (being the most exact of all sciences) has some inexact (non-standardized) terms when it comes to certain cases. The terms operator and function are used as synonymous in certain texts but the term operator is used in a a narrower sense (as a special kind of function) in other texts. Hence, it is impossible to say one usage is correct and the other is incorrect. In my view

1. The reader of a text has to use a concept according to and only according to the definition given in that particular text (contextual meaning),
2. International standards has to fix these kinds of problems in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Let $A$ and $B$ be ant two sets. Then $f:A\rightarrow B$ is said to be a $\textbf{function}$, if every element of $A$ is mapped to a unique element of $B$. Here requirement for $A$ and $B$ is only arbitrary sets.

Let $V_1,V_2$ be any two vector spaces. A map or a function $T:V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ is an $\textbf{operator}$. Here minimum requirement of $V_1,V_2$ be vector spaces. i.e., some algebraic structure should be there in domain and co-domain.

Comment: This makes much more sense than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, may I suggest that everyone think like this: instead of asking "*IS* an operator a function?" or "What *IS* an operator?" etc. we reframe the question like this:

"How are the words 'operator' and 'function' (and, if you like, 'mapping', 'transformation')  used when we are talking about mathematics?" [With the understanding that, despite the field being mathematics, we may find that these words are used ambiguously, inconsistently, to describe the same thing in some contexts and different things in others.... and that mathematical notation and vocabulary have emerged from historical usage, rather than being the result of conscious, top-down, rational decisions.]

Another way of approaching it -- really, the same idea as the above but starting from the other end, so to speak -- is to ask about the underlying mathematical reality (in this case, values which are being transformed to yield new values), to which the words "operator", "function" etc. are applied.

A footnote: at least one of the answers above implied that a function, unlike an operator, has only one input. Yes, this is how we start off learning about functions, but we quickly move on to functions of more than one input (those whose graphs describe surfaces, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between an operator and a function is simply that we've decided to call the operator an operator and we've decided to call the function a function. From a formal point of view, that's all there is to your question.

Any deeper meaning to the choice of words is merely a matter of convention -- when someone calls something an operator in some context, you know it is likely to be the sort of object that mathematicians call an operator in that context. So if you have familiarity with how mathematicians speak in a given context, you can infer a little bit more about what meaning the speaker is trying to convey.

In short, there is no difference in *denotation*; the only difference in the words is their *connotation*.

Answer (score 0):

[I.J. Maddox](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Elements_of_Functional_Analysis.html?id=ZZk4AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) defines a function in set-theoretical terms as follows:
"A function $f$ is defined to be a relation, suc that if $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,z)\in f$ then $y=z$". He then adds that "four other terms for function are map,mapping, operator and transformation". There is a certain restriction imbedded in this definition, so it may be natural to think of an operator as a more general term, namely, as a relation free from this restriction.

Comment: I am a little confused about using the terms map, mapping, operator and transformation to a function. I guess mapping is just an assignment from a domain to a co-domain and function has additional constraints of being any-to-one and being defined for all elements of the domain.

Comment: I agree. A lot if it is a matter of preferred wording. One has to kkep in mind though what one aims to achieve by accepting certain terminology. If all restrictions are removed, you get an object so generic that hardly any useful statement can be made about its properties

Answer (score 0):

Incase of Operators co-domain need to be some vector space but in case of function range/codomain need not be vector space.

Answer (score 0):

In Ch.6 of [“Specifying systems”](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/tla/book.html), Leslie Lamport distinguishes operators, as entities that take something (say a set), and give you back something (say another set). If the inputs don't form a set, then there does not exist a function that can serve as that operator, because a function *must* have a domain.

In other words, if an operator can be applied to any set, then the collection of all sets contains all the arguments that we can feed to it. However, in [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), such a collection is not a set. (Some call it "too big" to be a set. In any case, this is the same issue that Russell's paradox concerns).

Comment: A relevant thread can be found at the [TLA google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tlaplus/zWc0pwCK6vk).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can serve as an example for this discussion, if I'm interpreting the original question correctly, that is:

Use any OPERATIONS

$$1 \left\langle \,\Rule{1.4ex}{0ex}{0.4pt}\,\right\rangle 4 \left\langle \,\Rule{1.4ex}{0ex}{0.4pt}\,\right\rangle 9 \left\langle \,\Rule{1.4ex}{0ex}{0.4pt} \,\right\rangle = 16$$

Where $\,\left\langle \,\Rule{1.4ex}{0ex}{0.4pt}\,\right\rangle\,$ represents the space for an operator

MAKE THIS EQUATION TRUE

---

This example was posted in Facebook by Brilliant.org. One response that came repeatedly was:

$$1 + 4! - 9 = 16$$

This was immediately challenged by someone who stated that the factorial symbol $\,(!)\,$ represents a function rather than an operation and therefore the proposed answer violates the original requirement that specifies the use of operations. Nearly $400$ ensuing comments were posted in a debate about what constitutes an operator versus a function.

The debate expanded to include a debate on exponentiation (operation vs. function.)

I've Googled various sources on the web and the distinction between a mathematical operator vs. a mathematical function seems to be context dependent. Not as "cut and dried" as I had expected!

I hope this example is useful in terms of this discussion.

Comment: You are talking about operations, not *operators*.

Answer (score -1):

An operator is a mapping from one vector space or module to another. where a function is a map from any arbitrary set to another

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @BlackAdder Looks like an (attempted) answer to me...

Answer (score -1):

I am very late to this interesting discussion, but let me share my own practical view on the difference between *function* and *operator*.  An operator is normally an infix symbol which works on elements two at a time. A function is not so constrained - witness objections above to the factorial symbol, which is not infix and, at least conceptually, works on multiple elements simultaneously. In short, the difference between *function* and *operator* is notational and strongly conventional, not intrinsically mathematical.

Comment: This won't explain `unary` operators.